How to add the ability to pause so than voice recognition does not stop?
I have to do voice recognition in my Flutter App. I use speech_to_text package to do this. So, the main problem is listening stops when I pause in my speech. How can it be fixed? Are there any options to add a pause option? For example, I speak for a couple of seconds, then pause, the listening continues, and then I can continue the speech.
Here is my code. I will be glad of any help.
class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const StartPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StartPage> createState() => _StartPageState();
}

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
  final SpeechToText _speechToText = SpeechToText();
  bool _speechEnabled = false;
  String _recognizedText = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSpeech();
  }

  void _initSpeech() async {
    _speechEnabled = await _speechToText.initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _startListening() async {
    await _speechToText.listen(
      onResult: _onSpeechResult,
      listenFor: const Duration(seconds: 30),
      pauseFor: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    );
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _onSpeechResult(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      _recognizedText = result.recognizedWords;
    });
  }

  void _stopListening() async {
    await _speechToText.stop();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Speech Test')),
      floatingActionButton: IconButton(
        tooltip: 'Listen',
        onPressed: _speechToText.isNotListening ? _startListening : _stopListening,
        icon: Icon(_speechToText.isNotListening ? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 100),
            Text(_recognizedText),      
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

